# Media Foundation: multi-input MFT and topology connection order

Tags: ms-media-foundation

**The problem**

I'm writing a custom MFT with two inputs and one output (it merges two video streams into one).

My MFT requires media types to be set on its inputs **before** it can provide an output type.

I've set up my topology by connecting two source nodes (they take different streams from an aggregate media source) to my transform node, and then an EVR to my single output.

When I start the media session, I see that the topology invokes `SetInputType` on the first input, and it succeeds.

But then it immediately tries to get an output type: first by calling `GetOutputCurrentType` on my MFT, which returns `MF_E_TRANSFORM_TYPE_NOT_SET` as it is unable to provide one, and then by calling `GetOutputAvailableType`, which I made return `MF_E_TRANSFORM_TYPE_NOT_SET` as per the documentation (says *You must set the input types before setting the output types*; I also tried to output some partial media types but it's the same).

And here's the problem: after that, the topology seems to give up on my MFT: *it never calls `SetInputType` on the second input.*

**The question**

How can I force the topology to set all input types before dealing with the output?

Answer (score 2):

Read this : [Multiple input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825357/multiple-input-mft-in-microsoft-media-foundation)

Under Windows 7, it doesn't work...

You can provide a custom media session like i do in MFNode project.