# Media Foundation Transforms with Two Inputs

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Is it possible to insert a custom AsyncMFT, modified to accept multiple MFTs as inputs (e.g. MFTa and MFTb connecting to MFTc), into an IMFMediaSession (the mediasession object is created with MFCreateMediaSession)?  I've seen references online which state a custom mediasession is needed but this seems overkill.

I'm to the point where mftrace (including debugging in code) simply reports Catasrophic Failure when the MediaSession Starts (fails immediately after myMediaSession->Start(NULL, &startPos)).  The topology loads fine and both of the input MFTs work fine if they don't connnect to the same node.

Comment: On windows 7, it's not possible. I've already answer this question on stackoverflow. You need to provide a custom media session

Comment: FYI mofo77's earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268687/868014

Comment: @mofo77 Can this be done on Windows 10 without a custom media session?

Comment: @Roman R. : Are you referring to MFNode as well? From what I can tell it's actually connecting source1->MFTa and source2->MFTa then MFTa->MFTb and finally MFTb->Sink.  I am asking if it is possible for IMFMediaSessoin (not custom) to handle a multiplexed MFT in a topology (e.g. MFTa->MFTc and MFTb->MFTc then MFTc->Sink) as noted by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/about-mfts

Comment: My assumption is that it is possible, but I have not tried myself and I don't have an example  to refer to.

Comment: `actually connecting source1->MFTa and source2->MFTa ` - IT IS IMPOSSIBLE!!! `MediaSession` from `MFCreateMediaSession` supports one - ONLY ONE Source. I have faced with similar problem while wrote code for rendering video from TWO video files into the one video renderer - your code MUST aggregate two input sources into the ONE output source by [MFCreateAggregateSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreateaggregatesource), and then use only ONE Aggregated Source in `MediaSession`.

Comment: @EvgenyPereguda did you try creating a custom media session and it still failed?

Comment: @user7423607 The custom media session is a part of my project [CaptureManager SDK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK). In my view, the problem to use of `MediaSession` from `MFCreateMediaSession` is related with the limited functionality of it - playing video from files. For more complex solution it needs write a custom media session.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows 7 it is not possible.

Read this : [Mutl-input and multi-output](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/21596e11-c4e2-480a-b28f-9e2f5fa8820d/mutlinput-and-multioutput)

Becky Weiss from Microsoft gives answers :

> **The MFv1 pipeline isn't going to support multi-input MFTs**.  It happens that the Beta 2 Media Session doesn't explicitly validate against **this yet**
>
> I'd say that multi-input MFTs is something that future versions of Media Foundation can be expected to support; but for now, **we don't yet have that support**.

I suppose MFv1 refers to Vista, and MFv2 to windows 7.

The links you provide "About MFTs", just tell you you can write a transform with multiple input, that's all. But the problem is not Media Foundation transforms.

The problem is that the native media session is not able to handle multiple input stream from transform, whatever the type of connection you use (source > transform, transform > transform).

The message you are getting "Catasrophic Failure", was the same i was getting using AudioMixerMFT and the native media session.

> Can this be done on Windows 10 without a custom media session?

I don't know. Check mdsn forum link above, someone asks for this yesterday.

PS : If you choose to write a custom media session for your case, i can help. it would be a good exercise because of the use of AsyncMFT.

I moved the project wich contains a custom media session here : [github/mofo7777](https://github.com/mofo7777) (under MFNode > MFNodePlayer).